# Find abandoned entry in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array, and need to find the entry which does not have any link to other entries in the array.

```
const input = [
    { from: "Hong Kong", to: "Bejing" },
    { from: "New York", to: "London" },
    { from: "San Francisco", to: "Hong Kong" },
    { from: "Paris", to: "New York" },
    { from: "Bejing", to: "Singapore" },
    { from: "London", to: "San Francisco" },
  ];
```

If you see, all the entries except Paris -> New York has connection to other entries since Paris does not appear in any other entries.
How do I find this abandoned entry using javascript?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: What if multiple objects had an entry that didn't appear elsewhere (in order to try and anticipate a likely next-question), would you want an Array of "abandoned" entries or something else..? Do you want the Object returned, or just the entry String of"Paris"?

Comment: Also, isn't **Singapore** also *abandoned* ?

Comment: What do you consider a link? A direct path from `A -> B` of length 1 or could a link also be `A  -> C -> B` which would be a path from A to B of length 2? This certainly is something where you should create a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)).

Comment: I tried iterating the array with nexted for loop to compare from and to, but could not get it to work. I just want the entry string of Paris

Comment: well, Singapore is also abandoned. But for now, we can consider only the from field. So basically, the from field of an entry should not appear in any other entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array and hash the `to`'s. Then loop again, filtering out every `from` that isn't hashed. I use a hash `Set()` for fast lookups, instead of having to do a linear search with `.included()`.

```js
const input = [
    { from: "Hong Kong", to: "Bejing" },
    { from: "New York", to: "London" },
    { from: "San Francisco", to: "Hong Kong" },
    { from: "Paris", to: "New York" },
    { from: "Bejing", to: "Singapore" },
    { from: "London", to: "San Francisco" },
  ];

const tos = new Set(input.map(i => i.to));
const entry = input.filter(i => !tos.has(i.from));

console.log(entry);
```

Comment: wow, that was really fast...awesome..thanks so much